# data.table: Slice both dimensions, list of string columns

Tags: r, data.table

It seems to be a pretty standard question, but since I couldn't find it on SO yet, I believe it is a valid question.

Say I am given a table

```
> studTable
   age height
1:  12     48
2:  13     47
3:  14     70
4:  15     50
5:  16     62
6:  17     60
> str(studTable)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame
```

and a list that contains a subset of the column names as strings.

```
> LL = c('age', 'height')
```

How can I get the same as `studTable[1:5, list(age, height)]` with only using `studTable` and `LL`? My real use case is where I have a long list of columns (`LL`) that I want to reuse for both maintainability and readability.

```
> studTable[1:5, list(age, height)]
   age height
1:  12     48
2:  13     47
3:  14     70
4:  15     50
5:  16     62
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
studTable[1:5, ..LL]
#      age height
#  1:  12     48
#  2:  13     47
#  3:  14     70
#  4:  15     50
#  5:  16     62
```

Comment: Is there some documentation for the parameters that these indices take? Unlike normal functions, I cannot find documentations for these through google.

Comment: @FooBar.  You could check the data.table FAQ <http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf>.